# pandas recoding numeric variable into categorical variable

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to using pandas and have a very basic question.

What's the best way to recode a numeric variable into a categorical variable?

For example, I have a numeric variable x ranging from 1-1000. i want to create a new categorical variable of five categories. I tried the following but it seems a lot of typing (especially if i want to create 10-20 categories). Is there some standard or optimized way of achieving the same?

```
df_all['x_group'] = '0 pound'

df_all['x_group'][(df_all['x'] <=149)] = '0-1 pounds'

df_all['x_group'][(df_all['x'] >149) & (df_all['x'] <=249)] = '2 pounds'

df_all['x_group'][(df_all['x'] >249) & (df_all['x'] <=349)] = '3 pounds'

df_all['x_group'][(df_all['x'] >349) & (df_all['x'] <=449)] = '4 pounds'

df_all['x_group'][(df_all['x'] >449)] = '5 pounds'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your logic as a function and then apply the function to your dataframe using applymap(). Also, note that '0 pound' should probably read '0 pounds'.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just found that i could use pd.cut to put them into bins. It's a lot less typing.